# Nginx 1.4 on Debian 7 via apt-get

Tags: nginx, debian, linode

I cannot for the life of my figure out how to install nginx 1.4 via apt-get on a Debian 7 linode.

I added the following to `/etc/apt/source.list`:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ squeeze nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ squeeze nginx
```

I then try:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade --show-upgraded
apt-get install nginx
```

This always installs version 1.2.x. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Debian 7 and Ubuntu Lucid have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I pasted the wrong section from the nginx website, updated.

Comment: Debian 7 isn't "squeeze" either.